# SpringMVC lifecycle-- the overall view

Tags: spring-mvc

I'm way new to Spring.

I am looking to verify the following understanding of SpringMVC lifecycle-- to put things into places in the overall view:

The entire process is request-driven.

There is a [Front Controller pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_Controller_pattern) and the Front Controller in Spring MVC is [DispatcherServlet](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/DispatcherServlet.html).

Upon every incoming request from the user, Spring manages the 
entire life cycle as described in [here](http://eiconsulting.blogspot.com/2011/09/web-application-development-using.html).

In the overall view, [DispatcherServlet](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/DispatcherServlet.html) dispatches the request to a controller for a service at the back-end. 
Once this is done, it hands it in to the View component of MVC for its view to be prepared in response to the user.

In more detail,

- [DispatcherServlet](http://eiconsulting.blogspot.com/2011/09/web-application-development-using.html) uses Handlers to decide "which controller" to serve that request.
- The controllers are/should be "light-weighted"-- should be decoupled from 
  the service processes at back end as a good design practice-- they hold references to the service(s) and invoke the right one(s). 
  Their "mission" is to control the service process(es) for building the model and handing 
  it back to the dispatcher for the next step.
- The View component in itself has 2 parts: first the ViewResolver picks the right type of look for View to put the model into the final format for the user.

From the developer's angle-- the DispatcherServlet is a behind-the-scenes thing. 
All i do is to define, and configure it, if necessary, in web.xml.
As the developer, I instantiate an ApplicationContext (there are many ApplicationContext types-- i pick one depending on what i need, typically the 
WebApplicationContext(?) ). AplicationContext is the factory that creates all the servlets/beans including 
the DispatcherServlet, using their descriptions in the .xml files. The DispatcherServlet then runs behind the scenes and manages the 
entire process-- goes&gets the controllers, using the annotations or the their .xml descriptions, 
views, handlers, validators etc.

I am wondering whether this description is holds-- valid&complete, and whether there are big missing pieces in it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no good answer to your question.  "Sure" is as close as I can get.

You can configure spring using xml files or annotations or a combination of both.

You don't need to write servlets with Spring MVC, but you can if you want.  Mostly you can (maybe should) create controller classes (either by extending a Spring controller class or marking a class with the @Controller annotation).

The "mission" of the controller is to perform necessary processing of requests.  They do not just "control service processes"

There is no "hand it back" to the dispatcher.

The DispatchServlet must be configured in the web.xml file,
this is never optional.

You can (maybe should) have a layer between your controller classes and any web services that you will call from the controller classes.

You can have multiple applicationContexts or use a single applicationContext.

As often as not,
the View is a JSP file.

The Controller should add DTOs (data transfer objects) that are used by the view to display non-static information.
**EDIT:** I removed the mention of VO objects, I (like many, it seems) incorrectly conflated DTO and VO patterns.

There is no "behind the scenes".
The DispatcherServlet receives a request and passes it to the appropriate controller for processing.

Read section 17 of the [Spring Framework Reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.5.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc)

Answer (score 17):

Let's go into detail step by step

> DispatcherServlet uses Handlers to decide "which controller" to serve
>   that request

The [`DispatcherServlet`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/DispatcherServlet.html) maintains an ordered `List` of [`HandlerMapping`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/portlet/HandlerMapping.html) beans (which it loaded from the [`WebApplicationContext`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/WebApplicationContext.html)). A `HandlerMapping` is

> Interface to be implemented by objects that define a mapping between
>   requests and handler objects.

When the `DispatcherServlet` receives a request, it iterates over this list until it finds a matching handler object for the request in question. For simplicity, let's consider only [`RequestMappingHandlerMapping`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/RequestMappingHandlerMapping.html).

A bean of this type stores a mapping of [`@RequestMapping`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html) annotated methods (the actual `Method` object retrieved with reflection) stored as a [`HandlerMethod`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/method/HandlerMethod.html) instances and wrapped in [`RequestMappingInfo`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/RequestMappingInfo.html) objects that hold mapping data for matching the request, ie. URL, headers, and request parameters.

The `DispatcherServlet` retrieves the best matching `HandlerMethod` from these and any corresponding [`HandlerInterceptor`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerInterceptor.html) instances which you may have registered. It retrieves these as a [`HandlerExecutionChain`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerExecutionChain.html) object. It will first apply any [pre-handling](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerInterceptor.html#preHandle%28javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse,%20java.lang.Object%29) by `HandlerInterceptor`s. It will then try to invoke your `HandlerMethod`. This will typically (but not always) be a `@RequestMapping` annotated method inside a `@Controller` annotated class. This produces what Spring calls a **dispatch result**. The `DispatcherServlet` then applies [post-handling](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerInterceptor.html#postHandle%28javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse,%20java.lang.Object,%20org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView%29) by the `HandlerInterceptor`s. It finally processes the dispatch result depending on what it is. [You can see the supported return types for an idea of what that can be.](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-return-types)

> The controllers are/should be "light-weighted"-- should be decoupled
>   from the service processes at back end as a good design practice--
>   they hold references to the service(s) and invoke the right one(s).
>   Their "mission" is to control the service process(es) for building the
>   model and handing it back to the dispatcher for the next step.

In an MVC application, the controller controls operations by making changes to the model. You can do this directly in your controller or you can decouple it by implementing and providing service and business classes for that purpose. The controller depends on these, but not the other way around. Check out [multilayered architectures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multilayered_architecture).

The controller then builds the model ([`Model`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/ui/Model.html)) which the `DispatcherServlet` **possibly** makes available to the view. I say possibly because the controller can produce a response directly without any view (think `jsp`) involved.

> The View component in itself has 2 parts: first the ViewResolver picks
>   the right type of look for View to put the model into the final format
>   for the user.

In the typical case where the Controller handler method would return a [`Model`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/ui/Model.html), [`View`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/View.html), [`ModelAndView`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/portlet/ModelAndView.html), `String` (and some others) object, then a [`ViewResolver`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/ViewResolver.html) would handle finding the correct `View`. The `DispatcherServlet` then tries to render that view by first merging the model as you said. This usually means taking all `Model` attributes and putting them into the [`HttpServletRequest`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequestWrapper.html) attributes. The rendering step can involve rendering a `jsp`, generating XML, or anything at all really.

> From the developer's angle-- the DispatcherServlet is a
>   behind-the-scenes thing. All i do is to define, and configure it, if
>   necessary, in web.xml. As the developer, I instantiate an
>   ApplicationContext (there are many ApplicationContext types-- i pick
>   one depending on what i need, typically the WebApplicationContext(?)
>   ).

You don't actually need to instantiate it. The `DispatcherServlet` will do that itself (or use the [`ContextLoaderListener`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/ContextLoaderListener.html)'s) when the `Servlet` container calls `init()` on it. It will generate its own `WebApplicationContext`. [What you can do is decide which subclass of `WebApplicationContext` to use. This is an important choice if you want to load your context from XML or from a Java configuration. You can do this by providing an `<init-param>`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-servlet-sequence).

> AplicationContext is the factory that creates all the servlets/beans
>   including the DispatcherServlet, using their descriptions in the .xml
>   files. The DispatcherServlet then runs behind the scenes and manages
>   the entire process-- goes&gets the controllers, using the annotations
>   or the their .xml descriptions, views, handlers, validators etc.

The `ApplicationContext` is also known as the **Inversion of Control Container**. It does not include the `DispatcherServlet`. The `DispatcherServlet` is managed by the `Servlet` container and not by Spring. However, it does primarily take its configuration from Spring's `ApplicationContext` (`WebApplicationContext`). [It registers a number of special beans it finds in the context.](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-servlet-special-bean-types) [You can declare these yourself or let Spring do it for you with this little bit of XML](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-enable)

```
<mvc:annotation-driven>
```

This will (mostly) take care of doing what you describe, ie. registering handlers, validators, views, etc.

> I am wondering whether this description is holds-- valid&complete, and
>   whether there are big missing pieces in it.

Don't forget that a Spring MVC web application is a `Servlet` web application. The lifecycle of the application is therefore tied to the `Servlet` container.

Comment: wow, nice answer. I am off let reading a lot of your answer, all are fascinating. I have one query. Where do you read spring, spring-mvc related stuff apart from docs? any book/blog recommendation?

Comment: @piechuckerr I've really only read parts of the [official documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/) when they were relevant. I also step through a lot of the code while debugging and answering questions on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Spring Lifecycle Diagramm https://c1.staticflickr.com/1/14/89101625_26c5be9fd9_b.jpg