# How the Spring MVC @Controller's handler methods' parameters are automatically resolved during run-time?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, front-controller

How does the `DispatcherServlet` (or any other bean, supporting Spring MVC infrastructure), dynamically, resolve the signature of the handler method of the `@Component` instance, and how does it know, what parameters/types are expected, in which order, in that method?

If I have a "`@RequestMapping`-ed" handler method, in my `@Controller` instance, defining any version of its signature:

```java
public String f() {...}

public String f(Model model) {...}

public String f(HttpServletRequest, Model model) {...}

public String f(Model model, HttpServletRequest) {...}

public String f(SomeEntity se, Model model, HttpServletRequest, AnotherModel am) {...}

//so on..
```

would work fine, disregarding of parameter number, types, and order, which, eventually, are supplied with corresponding arguments, again - *disregarding* of their number, order and types.

There should be quite a work going underneath, to correctly instantiate expected arguments, pass them in a *proper* order, maybe even do some type-casting, if needed.. an so on, but I don't grasp the fundamentals of this.

I looked up the corresponding sources from `spring-webmvc` module, and sources of the `DispatcherServlet`; however, haven't got a firm grasp of the underlying mechanism.

I can guess, that some `BeanPostProcessor`s could be involved.. doing reflective accesses, and so on.. but even in this case, as I'm not certain on what's happening, I would very much appreciate any valuable input.

Answer (score 0):

In Spring MVC there are three implementations of HandlerMapping: BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping, SimpleUrlHandlerMapping and ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping.
You can read more about this subject here:
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-handler-mappings

Comment: I think this doesn't answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

I've not used Spring in years, but this post gives a pretty good step-by-step outline of the [spring mvc request lifecycle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20387678/6612762)

> When the DispatcherServlet receives a request, it iterates over this list until it finds a matching handler object for the request in question. For simplicity, let's consider only RequestMappingHandlerMapping.

> A bean of this type stores a mapping of @RequestMapping annotated methods (the actual Method object retrieved with reflection) stored as a HandlerMethod instances and wrapped in RequestMappingInfo objects that hold mapping data for matching the request, ie. URL, headers, and request parameters.

> The DispatcherServlet retrieves the best matching HandlerMethod from these and any corresponding HandlerInterceptor instances which you may have registered. It retrieves these as a HandlerExecutionChain object. It will first apply any pre-handling by HandlerInterceptors. It will then try to invoke your HandlerMethod. This will typically (but not always) be a @RequestMapping annotated method inside a @Controller annotated class. This produces what Spring calls a dispatch result. The DispatcherServlet then applies post-handling by the HandlerInterceptors.