# What is the very first function which is called during a rest api call in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, api, rest

I would like to set a breakpoint for debugging purpose. I call a rest api from Postman and I would like to check the very first point where the java application gets the call. Is there a listener? Where to set the breakpoint?

Comment: jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20387678/438154

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the [DispatcherServlet](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/DispatcherServlet.html) is what you are looking for. There is a lot of other stuff running before e.g. the servlet container and potential servlet filter, but the `DispatcherServlet` is a good starting point for debugging Spring MVC issues.

```java
protected void doDispatch(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception
```

The documentation is also quite good: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web.html#mvc-servlet

For Spring MVC Webflux applications have a look at [DispatcherHandler](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/DispatcherHandler.html) and set a breakpoint in `public Mono<Void> handle(ServerWebExchange exchange)`.